# Blazor fluent ui DialogService, <FluentDialogProvider/> error

Tags: c#, blazor, fluent-ui

I am using .net8 and blazor with Fluent UI library and I get an error that no provider is found even though I added it to App.razor at the end of MainLayout.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();
```

App.razor

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/js/loading-theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js" type="module" async></script>
```

MainLayout.razor

```
<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader>
        <Header/>
    </FluentHeader>

    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%" Class="page--container">
        <NavMenu/>

        <FluentBodyContent>
            @Body
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>
</FluentLayout>

<FluentDialogProvider/>
<FluentToastProvider/>
<FluentTooltipProvider/>
```

Header.razor

```
[Inject] public IDialogService DialogService { get; set; }

private async Task ToggleThemeHandler()
{
    var dialog = DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<MenuPanel>(new DialogParameters
    {
        Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
    });
    await dialog;
}
```

MenuPanel.razor

```
@implements IDialogContentComponent

<FluentDialogBody>
    Menu
</FluentDialogBody>
```

IDE Console

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: <FluentDialogProvider /> needs to be added to the main layout of your application/site. (Parameter 
'OnShowAsync')

System.ArgumentNullException: <FluentDialogProvider /> needs to be added to the main layout of your application/site. (Parameter 'OnShowAsyn
c') at Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.DialogService.ShowDialogAsync[TData](Type dialogComponent, TData data, DialogParameters param
eters) in /_/src/Core/Components/Dialog/Services/DialogService-Dialog.cs:line 17 at Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.DialogService.ShowDialogAsync[TDialog](DialogParameters parameters) in /_/src/Core/Components/Dialog/Services/DialogService-Dialog.cs:line 35 at Components.Layouts.MainLayout.Components.Header.ToggleThemeHandler() in **\Components\Layouts\MainLayout\Components\Header.razor:line 36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that is exactly the same issue described in a different modal library:
https://github.com/Blazored/Modal/issues/543

You are crossing interactivity boundaries. If you have `@rendermode` on your page, the boundary is here:

```
<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader>
        <Header/>
    </FluentHeader>

    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%" Class="page--container">
        <NavMenu/>

        <FluentBodyContent>
            @* Interactivity Boundary *@
            @Body
            @* Interactivity Boundary *@
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>
</FluentLayout>
```

Which means the `<Header` `<FluentLayout`, `<FluentHeader`, `<FluentStack`, etc is Server side rendered (SSR) and the page itself (`@Body`) has an interactivity, thus different context then SSR. They are not communicating with each other.

You have to unify the interactivity between the dialog and your page.

Here you have to either place all the Dialog elements inside the interactive page or put this into `MainLayout.razor`:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

Which will basically make all your pages InteractiveServer by default. (Which is something you might not want to, other solutions also exists).

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the [fluentui docs](https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/DialogService).

> For the  to work properly, it needs interactivity! If you are using "per page" interactivity or Server Side Rendering (ASP.NET Core 8 or above), make sure to add a @rendermode to either the provider itself or the component the provider is placed in.

So, you need to declare a `@rendermode` on the `MainLayout.razor` component, as mentioned on [@Alamkanambra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737008/11779494)

And/or on the `<FluentDialogProvider>` component like so.

```html
<FluentDialogProvider @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
```

---

Also, looking at the examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor/blob/dev/examples/Demo/Shared/Shared/DemoMainLayout.razor) seems like the dialog provider needs to be placed within the layout like so.

```html
<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader>
        <Header/>
    </FluentHeader>

    <FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%" Class="page--container">
        <NavMenu/>

        <FluentBodyContent>
            @Body
            <FluentDialogProvider @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer"/>
            <FluentToastProvider/>
            <FluentTooltipProvider/>
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>
</FluentLayout>
```